# Android Studio "ClassNotFoundException" occured while running the project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just start working with the new android studio.But when i run the project it throws an error

> update failed for AnAction with ID=EditSource: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.tools.idea.roots.ui.configuration.GradleProjectSettingsService

If any one knows the reason for this exception please help me below is the screen shot[image: Exception].Thanks in advance

Comment: post some code, please

Comment: Its an advice, not to start with Android Studio as it has many more bugs to be removed. I too got errors while i started using Android Studio, but then i switched over again to Eclipse.

Comment: @shree202 yeah i am using eclipse for last 2 years:)

Comment: @CássioGalvão i got this exception while running the project that is imported from eclipse.and when i start to create a project i got the exception "Unrecognized VM option '+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError'
Could not create the Java virtual machine."

Answer (score 2):

The reason is, that AS is broken. You should create an issue in the [bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list)....